# How do I invoke a Javascript that does not have a name using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing, web-scraping, invokescript

I would like to invoke a Javascript function on a web page that does not have a function name. Using C#, I would normally use `Webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("ScriptName")`. In this instance however, there is only a type attribute. This is what it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function(){
    SOME CODE HERE;
})();
</script>
```

Comment: That's not valid javascript. You are missing a `}`.

Answer (score 4):

That is a self-invoking function.
It will run as soon as that statement is executed.

It is not possible to run it again without modifying the script.

Answer (score 2):

As long as this closure does not export methods to the global namespace, you can't

Answer (score 0):

Expose a Method.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function(){
    MyFunction = function() {
      SOME CODE HERE;
    }
})();
</script>


Webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("MyFunction");
```